# php regex to remove square brakets and brakets from string

Tags: php, regex

I'm using this to clean the file name but it still lets square brakets and brackets through, these ones "{}()[]". I am trying to have regex remove those.

```
$clean = preg_replace("([^\w\s\d\.\-_~,;:\[\]\(\)]|[\.]{2,})", '', $file_name);
```

Comment: `[^...]` is  a negated character class, and you have `\[\]\(\)` in it. Remove `\[\]\(\)` if you need to match them. Note `[\.]{2,}` = `\.{2,}`

Comment: This question would be more clear if you offered ~5 sample strings and your exact desired result for each string.  By representing some of the fringe cases, you clarify the variability of your project data and make it easier to identify correct from incorrect answers.  Please [edit] your question so that this page can be more useful to researchers.  Misspelling and misusing the term "brakets" is making this question a little too confusing.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I meant to remove these "{}()[]" from any file names

Comment: @answer I believe I can provide a better answer than you have received.  Please supply a handful of strings to be sanitized and your expected result for each string.  Are you allowing whitespace characters in your filenames? As a general rule, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove square brackets from the expression (actually, this expression removes everything that is not any of the character expressions there)
Also `{2,}` implies you only can remove them if *2 or more* characters match inside a sequence. You can use `{1,}` or `+`.

```
$clean = preg_replace("([^\w\s\.\-_~]+)", '', $file_name);
```

If you want to remove repeated elements with `{2,}` this could be another additional replace like this:

```
$clean = preg_replace("([.]{2,})", '.', $clean);
```

For example:

```
<?php
$file_name="test#&ing %^& (123y456) aaa [678n789]..xxx.txt";
$clean = preg_replace("([^\w\s\.\-_~]+)", '', $file_name);
$clean = preg_replace("([.]{2,})", '.', $clean);
print_r($clean); // 'testing 123y456 aaa 678n789.xxx.txt'
?>
```

> 

Comment: @answerSeeker If won't work well if you happen to have any `|` characters in the filename. Also, it is a mistake to have two `\.` in the negated character class. There was no need to remove the pattern that matched two or more `.` from the original regex.

Comment: Why is `\.` in the negated character class twice?  Why is the underscore explicitly mentioned in the negated character class after `\w`?  A dot does not need to be escaped within a character class.  `{1,}` is more simply expressed as `+`.  `[.]` is more simply expressed as `\.`.  I do not recommend using `()` as the pattern delimiter because it tricks the reader's eye about where or not there is a capturing group.